# When elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer finishes, source buffer closes

Tags: elpy

And the first thing I do is to reopen the file.

`elpy-shell-send-region-or-buffer` is bound to `C-c C-c`.  This sends the buffer to an ipython buffer.  I've set a breakpoint with `pdb.set_trace()` and it stops there.  I use `c` (continue), with no further breakpoints, and the program ends. But the source buffer closes.

I'd like to find some way to keep the source buffer open.

I did it a long time ago, but I'd assume this one code from my `.emacs` should be what's necessary to set up sending from the source buffer to ipython:

```lisp
(elpy-enable)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'elpy-mode)
```

Comment: Emacs 27.1 on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: I'm if not amused, then at least bemused.